# Who is my friend who enjoys greasy food?

Tags: riddle

I have a friend who lives really close to my house. I like him a lot, but he's got some really weird habits.

He demands that I take him out to dinner pretty frequently—once or twice a week, it feels like. He likes to go to this one place that serves really, *really* greasy food. Like, I can't even eat it, it's that bad. He eats a hell of a lot, too; the food is actually pretty cheap, but the bill usually comes out to around $30! No wonder he weighs over 300 pounds.

He spends a lot of time outside, even in freezing cold weather; he doesn't seem to mind the cold at all. He really enjoys running, and he's surprisingly fast for such a big guy! He could easily outrun me any day of the week.

He only takes a shower with soap about once a week, if that. Disgusting, right?

But all in all, he's a really good friend, and I wouldn't give him up for ten thousand dollars.

**Who is he?**

Comment: 30$ is very locale-specific, 300lbs is a broad under-statement, and 1-2 a week depends on how much you hang out with your friend really. (also, shower once a week is probably not even necessary)

Comment: At first I thought this was IPS and I was so confused...

Comment: @njzk2 wow, next you'll probably be telling us about how a person doesn't go from being a baby crawling on all fours in the morning to walking with a cane in the evening...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Is your cohort a

> Car - Fill it up with petrol (light oil) at the gas station quite often (this cost is low compared to many places). Park it outside in all weathers and it can go more than 100 mph even though large. Wash the car say weekly. Cost of $10 000 is fair for a recentish vehicle.

Comment: agghhh beat me to it ... :-)

Comment: @deepthought An anagram of your username is *the dope thug* :O ;)

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that your friend is:

> man's best friend... a dog

Comment: Dogs don't usually weigh over 300 pounds or eat $30's worth of food at one meal. (But they sometimes do...)

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! While you're here, why don't you take the [tour](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tour) and earn your first badge? For future reference, please enclose your answer in spoiler tags (`>!`) like I've edited, and perhaps provide some explanation for less obvious parts (like the 300lbs part). Hope you can stay and contribute more to the community!

Comment: @TannerSwett from the accepted answer, your friend is usually nowhere close to 140 kg, and a meal for your friend is not anywhere close to 30$ (presumably USD?) in most parts.